# Find User Login and Logout activities using SQL select query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one **UserActivity** table, which contains UserID, DateTime, Activity columns.
Table structure is:

```
Id    UserID         DateTime             Activity
123    abc      2023-08-24 09:30:50        Login
125    abc      2023-08-24 09:34:23        Login
150    abc      2023-08-24 09:38:04        Logout
178    abc      2023-08-24 13:23:12        Login
200    abc      2023-08-24 15:50:34        Logout
300    abc      2023-08-24 16:43:02        Login
505    abc      2023-08-25 10:32:12        Login
507    abc      2023-08-25 12:36:44        Logout
```

I want Output, which will return all the login datetime with it's correspondent logout datetime. If Logout datetime is not present for particular login then it should be blank.

**Output**:

```
UserID        LoginDateTime            LogoutDateTime
 abc       2023-08-24 09:30:50
 abc       2023-08-24 09:34:23       2023-08-24 09:38:04
 abc       2023-08-24 13:23:12       2023-08-24 15:50:34
 abc       2023-08-24 16:43:02
 abc       2023-08-25 10:32:12       2023-08-25 12:36:44
```

I have tried below query, but it's not giving correct Output.

```
*SELECT
login.UserID,
login.DateTime As Login,
LogOut.DateTime As Logout
from
  UserActivity login
Left JOIN
  UserActivity LogOut ON Login.UserID=Logout.UserID
  AND login.Activity='login.label'
  AND Logout.Activity='logout.label'
  AND TO_CHAR(Login.DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(Logout.DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND Login.DateTime<Logout.DateTime
Where login.UserID='abc'
  Order by login.UserID,login.DateTime;*
```

Please help to achieve above result.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that a user only has one login at a time? Based on the data you've shown, without a session id of some kind if a user can have multiple simultaneous logins then there is no way to determine which logins go with which logouts.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to self-join the table; it is more efficient to use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       datetime as LoginDateTime,
       LogoutDateTime
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         datetime,
         activity,
         LEAD(CASE activity WHEN 'Logout' THEN datetime END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY userid
           ORDER BY datetime
         ) AS logoutdatetime
  FROM   useractivity u
)
WHERE  activity = 'Login';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE useractivity (
  Id       NUMBER,
  UserID   VARCHAR2(20),
  DateTime DATE,
  Activity VARCHAR2(6)
);

INSERT INTO useractivity (id, userid, datetime, activity)
  SELECT 123, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 09:30:50', 'Login'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 125, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 09:34:23', 'Login'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 150, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 09:38:04', 'Logout' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 178, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 13:23:12', 'Login'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 200, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 15:50:34', 'Logout' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 300, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-24 16:43:02', 'Login'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 505, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-25 10:32:12', 'Login'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 507, 'abc', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-25 12:36:44', 'Logout' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USERID | LOGINDATETIME | LOGOUTDATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2023-08-24 09:30:50 | *null* |
| abc | 2023-08-24 09:34:23 | 2023-08-24 09:38:04 |
| abc | 2023-08-24 13:23:12 | 2023-08-24 15:50:34 |
| abc | 2023-08-24 16:43:02 | *null* |
| abc | 2023-08-25 10:32:12 | 2023-08-25 12:36:44 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vOKogK-5)

Comment: I want to join this query with User table from where I will get Username.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad Then use a `JOIN` to that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    L.UserID,
    L.DateTime AS LoginDateTime,
    MAX(R.DateTime) AS LogoutDateTime
FROM
    UserActivity L
LEFT JOIN
    UserActivity R ON L.UserID = R.UserID
                    AND R.Activity = 'Logout'
                    AND R.DateTime > L.DateTime
WHERE
    L.UserID = 'abc'
    AND L.Activity = 'Login'
GROUP BY
    L.UserID, L.DateTime
ORDER BY
    L.UserID, L.DateTime;
```